# MYSQL Trigger/Constraint for set of equal column value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, constraints

In the following table:

```
Country Name             |  Country Code |  isStandardName
----------------------------------------------------------

United States            |  USA          |    false
----------------------------------------------------------
United States of America |  USA          |    True 
----------------------------------------------------------
Yankees                  |  USA          |   false
```

There is a situation where there are different names for countries such as United States of America / United States with the similar country Code (in this case, USA) however one of them can be the standard name. In this case easiest solution is to enforce a constraint in which similar country codes can have only one Boolean true in the isStandardName section at a time.

In other words how to make "CountryCode , 'true'" unique for a set of equal countryCode names by triggers/constraints?

Any suggestion on how to enforce this constraint?

Comment: If we try to add `unique(countryCode, isStandardName)` it will also not allow more than 1 boolean `false`. So as per requirement it would be good to create `trigger`.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of `isStandardName`, have a `priority` column comprised of an `UNSIGNED INTEGER`.  Then one can define a `UNIQUE` constraint over `(countryCode, priority)` and treat some magic value (e.g. 0) as the "*standard name*".

Comment: But unique (countryCode, isStandardName) will not work if we have three USAs and two falses! The number of equal countryCodes may vary up to 10 even!

Comment: I think adding one more column will just make situation more complex. I am trying to avoid adding more columns.

Comment: @FidEliO: That's why I said "*instead of...*".

Comment: But your constraint fails at the new table i changed, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it while keeping the table as one (as it is).

First, Create procedure for checking canonical countries integration

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `db`.`check_canonical_integrity` (IN new_countrycode
  VARCHAR(10), IN new_iscanonical tinyint(1))
BEGIN
SELECT sum(iscanonical) into @canonicalsum from `gapminder_db`.`COUNTRY_CODES` WHERE countrycode = new_countrycode; 
IF (@canonicalsum + new_iscanonical) > 1 THEN
   SET @msg := 'More than one canonical countrycode cannot exit.';
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
END IF;
END
//DELIMITER ;
```

Second, we call the above before insert, you can do the same in delete:

```
DELIMITER &&
 CREATE TRIGGER `db`.`check_canonical_flag_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON
 `COUNTRY_CODES`

 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
      CALL check_canonical_integrity(New.countrycode, New.iscanonical);
    END&&
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend dropping the column 'isStandardName'. Create a table standard_country. Created a relationship between country and standard_country. Create a view using left join and change the model to use the new structure.

Example.

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` char(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ISO 3166-1 alpha-3',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `country` (`country`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `country` (`id`, `country`, `code`)
VALUES
    (1,'United States','USA'),
    (2,'United States of America','USA'),
    (3,'Yankees','USA');

CREATE TABLE `standard_country` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key` (`code`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `standard_country_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `standard_country` (`id`, `country_id`, `code`)
VALUES
    (1,2,'USA');

create or replace view countries_view as
select country.id country_id 
, country
, country.code
, COALESCE( (standard_country.id > 0) , 0 ) isStandard
from `country`
left join `standard_country`
on country.id = standard_country.country_id

-- example result
select * from countries_view ;

country_id    country    code    isStandard
1    United States    USA    0
2    United States of America    USA    1
3    Yankees    USA    0
```

Comment: Nice solution. But I was thinking of avoiding creating new table in my case since this request is coming from our DBA.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation in case I will use triggers?

Comment: @FidEliO I had a look at triggers ... messy ... I suggest showing this solution to your DBA. Having one record in a table that may change it's value if another record in the same table has changed it's value can be handled in the data access layer if your DBA wants to keep the old structure.

Comment: I agree with you. But he has this IDEA that DAL should not be coded with handling such stuff. But thanks for your answer.